# MySQL remove final part of a string after specific character

Tags: mysql, replace

I need to remove the last part of a string in a column where I have a field named "path" that looks like:

```
images/prop/images/2034/22399_2034.JPG
```

I need everything after the last "/" to be deleted, in order to have

```
images/prop/images/2034/
```

instead of

```
images/prop/images/2034/22399_2034.JPG
```

I have no idea if this is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

You can combine MySQL's [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) and [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) functions:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1) FROM path)
FROM   my_table
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dde74/1/0).

Comment: can you tell me the syntax in order to update the whole table?

Comment: I am trying to update the whole data after select but I cant find the right code, help...

Comment: @ol30cean0: `UPDATE my_table SET path = TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1) FROM path)`.